# Prettier removes parentheses around conditional in ternary expression

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator, react-icons

Prettier removes parentheses around conditional in ternary expression. Is there any way to set `false` in json file? or any other way? I still want the prettier ofcourse but I just don't want () to be removed example like in a code below. `<FaCodepen />` is react-icon.

```
// What I want to do
{navOpen ? (
   <FaCodepen />
) : (
   <FaCodepen />)}

// After using Prettier
{navOpen ? <FaCodepen /> : <FaCodepen />}
```

I don't know if this is the reason but `{navOpen ? <FaCodepen /> : <FaCodepen />}` does not work so I want to try out with the original.

Comment: There's no functional difference between the two formats. If you have a bug it's not related to the prettier change

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I solved the problem what I had.